# Create a POSTagger model

Tags: android, nlp

I am trying to create a model that takes an input sentence on an offline Android App and returns me the parts of speech for that sentence. Now the input language will be an Indian Language so I am trying to train my own model for the job. I already have my tagged data for training in the language I will use.

I also came across Opennlp models which do the same job for English Language. Now is it possible to create a model and use that with the Opennlp library, kind of a custom Opennlp model. I am not sure if this is really possible.

Alternatively, I thought of training my model with some Machine Learning algorithm and then using it but I'm clueless as to how I'll use that model as I don't have a predefined library with all the available commands as I had with Opennlp.

Just to sum up, I need to create my own model to integrate in an Android app that will detect the parts of the speech of the input. The app should run in offline mode, however, the training part and other pre-processing stuff can be done online.

Comment: If you have your own data, you can refer [this](http://www.phontron.com/slides/nlp-programming-en-04-hmm.pdf) to write your own POS tagging algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward to train models with OpenNLP with your own data, either with the command-line tools or through the API. For part-of-speech tagging, see: https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger.training

Answer (score 0):

To find POS of the sentence of an Indian language from scratch is a big task , first you have to create a huge corpus with correctly annotated pos tags and you have to train a model (which are already available for english).

So the feasible approach would be using language translate APIs to translate the sentence into english and perform your further task/analysis.